# How parameter passing works with the call stack on nested function calls

Tags: javascript, function, assembly, process, operating-system

Say you have these calls (JavaScript, just making this up for the article):

```
function start() {
  let a = 10
  let x = doX(a)
  let b = 20
  doY(a, b + x)
  b = 30
  x--
  return doZ(a + (b * x))
}

function doX(x) {
  let a = x * 2
  let b = doZ(x) + 2
  return doZ(a + b)
}

function doY(x, y) {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${x + y}.txt`, 'hello world')
}

function doZ(x) {
  return Math.pow(2, x)
}
```

So not to get too into the weeds about the exact representation a compiler would make of this, I am just mainly interested in demonstrating some nested variables and how they are used in between function calls.

So essentially we have this at each "frame" (a term which I just mean to be all of the variables defined before the upcoming function call):

```
1. a = 10 [call doX(a)]
  1. a = x * 2 [call doZ(x)]
  2. a = x * 2, b = doZ(x) + 2 [call doZ(a + b)]
2. x = ?1, a = 10, b = 20 [call doY(a, b + x)]
  1. ... ignored, just something outside of our scope
3. x = ?2, a = 10, b = 30 [call doZ(a + (b * x))]
  1. just a return
```

So at the top level, both `x` and `b` change their values. Otherwise all the other variable are just declared once. But in reality function calls could be 20 deep, with 20 variables each, some of them being assigned 10 times+. So there would be this situation times 10 let's say, if not more.

Basically, I am wondering what the call stack would look like in each of these frames. Particularly how the local variables are stored/restored after certain points.

For example, what happens between points (2) and (3)? The `x` and `b` variables are both redefined. What goes into the call stack before the function called at (2)? What goes into the call stack inside of (2)? And what goes into the call stack after (2)?

Say we had a much more complicated situation:

```
let a = 10
let b = 20
draw(a++, b)
draw(a++, b)
draw(a++, b)
draw(a++, b)
...x100
```

What happens then? Is `b` pushed and popped every call to `draw`?Or is it somehow optimized so it doesn't have to be stored on the stack every time? This sort of stuff...

Pretty much I am just trying to get a sense of how to build a call stack from scratch, and am confused as to what you actually put onto the call stack, and when/how/what you actually pop when a function returns. Because to me, in my head, when you do `let b = 10`, it just "stays around in the function scope" until the function is done, but that's not realistic. I am not paying attention to the call stack, mainly because higher-level languages don't require you too, and so I don't have any sense of it.WHat I would like to gain is an intuition for what the call stack looks like at these points/frames. I have seen the wikipedia (and other) diagrams of the rectangle drawing of a stack, but they aren't very helpful. What I would really think was useful is some pseudocode so I could see, perhaps in an array of "frames", what each "step" or "frame" would look like in terms of JavaScript objects or structs (sort of thing), something like:

```
var callStackAtEachFrame = [
  {
    a: 10
  },
  [
    {
      a: 10
    },
    {
      a: x * 2
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 10
    },
    {
      a: x * 2,
      b: doZ(x) + 2
    },
    {
      something: Math.pow(2, x)
    }
  ]
]
```

I don't really know, but it seems that visualizing in a more code way like this, how things push and pop from the callstack, would be helpful in knowing how to build one.

Does it look something like this in reality?

```
function start() {
  let a = 10
  PUSH(a)
  let x = doX(a)
  POP(a, x)
  let b = 20
  PUSH(a, x, b)
  doY(a, b + x)
  POP(a, x, b)
  b = 30
  x--
  PUSH(a, x, b)
  return doZ(a + (b * x))
}

function doX(x) {
  let a = x * 2
  PUSH(a)
  let b = doZ(x) + 2
  POP(a, b)
  return doZ(a + b)
}

...
```

Also, I am not really to interested how *JavaScript* itself does it, I am interested in a language-agnostic way.

Comment: `doY(a, b + x)` will still pass two arguments since `doY` expects that. The compiler will `push(a, b + x)`. Furthermore, most calling conventions return result in register(s) so the caller would not `pop` that. Function arguments are usually treated as local variables of the callee. Their values are not expected to be preserved, hence if you want to call `draw(a++, b)` multiple times you will need to set up both arguments for each.

Answer (score 2):

First, in most languages, local variables (modulo closures) cannot be modified or accessed outside of the scope of the function in which they are declared, so variables in another function are wholly independent even if their names are the same as the names of variables in some other function.  I say this because your example makes reuse of variable names in different functions, which, I think leaves some room for confusion.

As you are noting, the stack is not just for function calling and parameter passing — it also stores local variables.  However, while function call arguments and return addresses are sometimes pushed onto the stack, local variables are typically allocated in a group rather than being pushed.

Most language implementations create all the local storage a function will need (for local variables and temporaries) once at the top of the function in what is called [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue).

Effectively, all the pushing and popping you might envision for local variables is flattened and combined into a single group allocation despite that the local variables may be in different scopes inside the same function.

```
fn(x) {
    int a = ...;
    if (...) {
        int b = ...;
    }
    while (...) {
        int c = ...;
    }
}
```

Assuming here that local storage is needed for `a`, `b` and `c`, the language implementation will allocate up to 3 int's worth of local storage once in prologue and deallocate that once in epilogue.  (It is possible for the language to allocate less, if it realizes, for example, that liveness/storage durations for `b` and `c` don't overlap, they could share the same storage location.)

A group allocation like i'm describing is done in prologue typically by subtracting from the stack pointer rather than pushing values onto the stack.  The block of storage is essentially uninitialized (though various language implementations have varying techniques to ensure variables are properly initialized during execution).

---

Formal parameters are similar to local variables but they are initialized with values by some caller whereas local variables are initialized within the same function that uses them.

```
fn(x) {
    a = fn2(x+1,x-1);
    ... a ..;
}

fn2(y,z) { return y * z; }
```

in the above, theoretically, `x+1` and `x-1` are evaluated in the context of function `fn`.  When `fn2` is actually invoked, we will see that `y:=x+1` and `z:=x-1` and that this happens before the first line of `fn2` actually runs.  This initialization of the formal parameters `y` and `z` actually happens before `fn2` is actually called, and so, some mechanism must be used in order to allow this before they technically exist as formal parameters in called function `fn2`.

For the stack-based parameter passing machine, this mechanism is pushing.

Each push allocates one variable, which will transition from being the value evaluated for an actual argument into a formal parameter for the callee.

To accomplish the above call on a stack-based machine, we would evaluate `x-1` then push that onto the stack; next evaluate `x+1` and push that onto the stack.  Finally, invoke `fn2`, which pushes the return address onto the stack.  When `fn2` starts, there are thus 3 things on the stack that it can rely upon: a return address, `y` and `z`.

(The parameters are pushed right to left by the caller, so they end up left to right in memory — this has to do with varargs in C.)

If `fn2` wants local storage, it will allocate it by subtracting from the stack pointer.  When it does that, the are now 4 things on the stack: local storage block, a return address, `y` and `z`.

When `fn2` is done it releases its local storage, and then returns to the caller using the return address that was provided by the call, which was pushed onto the stack.  Doing the return pops the return address off the stack, so typically then, the caller pops off the formal parameters it created to call the function.

You might ask: where does the return value go?  If it went onto the stack the caller would have to provide space for it next to the parameters — however, typically the return value is placed in a CPU register to avoid this.

Comment: This is getting there, thank you! :) Why is there a difference between [function parameters](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions) and the [local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/considerations-for-writing-prolog-epilog-code?view=vs-2019) then?

Comment: The values for parameters are defined in one function (the caller) yet used in another (the callee), whereas local variables are both defined and used in the same function.

Comment: Mind showing some more pseudocode including the function parameters and local variables in how the stack works? Not assembly code but perhaps C or JS style pseudocode to show how the stack works ㋛㋛㋛

Comment: @LancePollard and Erik: In asm, a nested function that accesses variables in the outer scope needs a pointer to the parent stack frame.  I think this is called a "static chain pointer".  This only gets tricky if you want to create a function pointer to a nested function; C doesn't support that.  (GNU C does as an extension, but it's pretty hairy.)  If you want to support it I'd recommend designing it in so you have first-class support for pointers to nested functions vs. plain function pointers that don't have an outer scope context as an extra argument.)